# Induced homology of map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Suppose that $Y$ and $Z$ are both path connected with base points and $f$$:$$X$ $\to$$Z$ and  $g$ $:$ $X$ $\to$ $Z$ .

I want to prove that :

> a map $($$f$,$g$$)$ $:$ $X$ $\to$ $Y$$\lor$$Z$ induces a homology $($$f$$_*$ , $g$$_*$$)$ $:$ $H$$_i$$X$ $\to$ $H$$_i$$Y$ $\oplus$ $H$$_i$$Z$ .
>   How can i show this ?

I think that we must use the fact $H$$_i$$($$X$$\lor$$Y$$)$$\simeq$$H$$_i$$X$$\oplus$$H$$_i$$Y$ to prove .

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try Mayer Vietoris.

Assuming that $Y,Z$ are locally contractible, construct open sets $U,V$ that cover $Y,Z$ "plus some change," so that $U \cap V$ is contractible.

Then, there will be an exact sequence

$$\dots H_n(U \cap V) \to H_n(U) \oplus H_n(V) \to H_n(X) \to H_{n-1}(U \cap V) \to\dots$$

...but we will know that $H_i(U \cap V)=?$ for $i>0$.

Comment: it is absolutely $0$

Comment: and hence by exactness...

Comment: If i want to use that fact how i can prove this ?

Comment: What fact? What is "this"?

Comment: The fact that say n-th homology of wedge sum of two path connected spaces equals to direct sum of two n-th homology of each other